# Should I inline long code in a loop, or move it in a separate method?

Tags: java, performance, coding-style

Assume I have a loop (any while or for) like this:

```
loop{
    A long code.
}
```

From the point of time complexity, should I divide this code in parts, write a function outside the loop, and call that function repeatedly?

I read something about functions very long ago, that calling a function repeatedly takes more time or memory or like something, I don't remember it exactly. Can you also provide some good reference about things like this (time complexity, coding style)?

Can you also provide some reference book or tutorial about heap memory, overheads etc. which affects the performance of program?

Comment: See [When to optimize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize). Computers are fast and getting faster. My time is worth much more to me than a few extra cycles on a CPU. While there are a number of environments with *hard performance limits*, they are 1) known; 2) planned for in design; 3) supported with benchmarks/analysis.

Comment: beware of [premature optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize). however making your code neat is always a good practice.

Comment: remember that a functions with short bodies of code tend to get jit-ed at the call site see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HotSpot

Comment: See also [this question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/96994/how-to-significantly-improve-java-performance) quoting Martin Fowler: "This just needs well-factored code and small methods - essentially this allows Hotspot to do a better job of optimizing and for CPUs to be more efficient in caching the code as it's running."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The performance difference is probably very minimal in this case.  I would concentrate on clarity rather than performance until you identify this portion of your code to be a serious bottleneck.

It really does depend on what kind of code you're running in the loop, however.  If you're just doing a tiny mathematical operation that isn't going to take any CPU time, but you're doing it a few hundred thousand times, then inlining the calculation might make sense.  Anything more expensive than that, though, and performance shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: My experience is that the Java Compiler optimizations are in 99% of the cases way better than anything I try to do to optimize my code. I.e. something like what you're describing might be done in the optimization process of the compiler. --> Go for readable, maintainable and extendable code!

Comment: AFAIK, there's no reason for gaining *any* performance. Let JIT inline it for you. Keep the methods short for readability and also for performance, as JIT works better with short methods.

Answer (score 1):

There is an overhead of calling a function.

So if the "long code" is fast compared to this overhead (and your application cares about performance), then you should definitely avoid the overhead.

However, if the performance is not noticably worse, it's better to make it more readable, by using a (or better multiple) function.

Comment: No, there's normally no overhead, the JIT can inline it easily, if needed. Do not avoid the more readable code for performance here, since there's no measurable gain. Actually, JIT works better on shorter methods!

Answer (score 1):

Rule one of performance optmisation: Measure it.

Personally, I go for readable code first and then optimise it IF NECESSARY. Usually, it isn't necessary :-)

See the first line in [CHAPTER 3 - Measurement Is Everything](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/performance/1st_edition/html/JPMeasurement.fm.html)

> "We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time:
>   premature optimization is the root of all evil." - Donald Knuth

In this case, the difference in performance will probably be minimal between the two solutions, so writing clearer code is the way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

There really isnt a simple "tutorial" on performance, it is a very complex subject and one that even seasoned veterans often dont fully understand.  Anyway, to give you more of an idea of what the overhead of "calling" a function is, basically what you are doing is "freezing" the state of your function(in Java there are no "functions" per se, they are all called methods), calling the method, then "unfreezing", where your method was before.

The "freezing" essentially consists of pushing state information(where you were in the method, what the value of the variables was etc) on to the stack, "unfreezing" consists of popping the saved state off the stack and updating the control structures to where they were before you called the function.  Naturally memory operations are far from free, but the VM is pretty good at keeping the performance impact to an absolute minimum.

Now keep in mind Java is almost entirely heap based, the only things that really have to get pushed on the stack are the value of pointers(small), your place in the program(again small), and whatever primitives you have local to your method, and a tiny bit of control information, nothing else.  Furthermore, although you cannot explicitly inline in Java(though Im sure there are bytecode editors out there that essentially let you do that), most VMs, including the most popular HotSpot VM, will do this automatically for you.  http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Networking/HotSpot/inlining.html

So the bottom line is pretty much 0 performance impact, if you want to verify for yourself you can always run benchmarking and profiling tools, they should be able to confirm it for you.

Answer (score 0):

From a *execution speed* point of view it shouldn't matter, and if you still believe this is a bottleneck it is easy to measure.

From a *development performance perspective*, it is a good idea to keep the code short. I would vote for turning the loop contents into one (or more) properly named methods.

Answer (score 0):

Forget it! You can't gain any performance by doing the job of the JIT. Let JIT inline it for you. Keep the methods short for readability and also for performance, as JIT works better with short methods.

There are microptimizations which may help you gain some performance, but don't even think about them. I suggest the following rules:

- Write clean code using appropriate objects and algorithms for readability and for performance.
- In case the program is too slow, profile and identify the critical parts.
- Think about improving them using better objects and algorithms.
- As a last resort, you may also consider microoptimizations.